# i made custom strsplit function but output is weird

Tags: c++, strsplit

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int ft_strlen(char *str, char ascii[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (!ascii[(short)str[i]] && str[i])
        ++i;
    return (i);
}

int word_count(char *s, char *ascii) {
    int i = 0, cnt = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        if (ascii[(short)s[i]])
            while (ascii[(short)s[i]])
                ++i;
        else {
            ++cnt;
            while (!ascii[(short)s[i]] && s[i])
                ++i;
        }
    }
    return (cnt);
}

char **ft_strsplit(char *s, char *ascii) {
    if (!s)
        return NULL;
    int wc = word_count(s, ascii);
    char **ans = (char **)malloc(wc);
    char *result;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k;
    while (wc--) {
        result = (char *) malloc(ft_strlen(s + i, ascii) + 1);
        for (k = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++k) {
            if (!ascii[(short)s[i]])
                result[k] = s[i];
            else {
                result[i] = '\0';
                ans[j++] = result;
                //inside the printf
                printf("%d %s\n", j - 1, ans[j - 1]);
                while (ascii[(short)s[i]])
                    ++i;
                break;
            }
        }
        result[i] = 0;
        ans[j] = result;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, ans[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    char ascii[256] = {0,};
    char d[] = ", ";
    int i = -1;
    while (d[++i])
        ascii[(short)d[i]] = 1;
    char str[90] = "it, is my, day 2,";
    char** ptr = ft_strsplit(str, ascii);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I splited string and printing them, inside the printf printed well (plz look at the comment) but another printf's first string output weird.. I don't know why this happening. below is this code's output.

```
0 it
1 is
2 my
3 day
4 2
0 8P
1 is
2 my
3 day
4 2
0 8P
1 is
2 my
3 day
4 2
```

I expect all printf output like

```
0 it
1 is
2 my
3 day
4 2
```

I tried this code at https://cpp.sh/ this site. if this output depends on compiler plz tell me.

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages, and a "string split" function would do very different things and use very different types in the two languages. So please don't tag multiple languages, only the one you're actually program in.

Comment: With that said, you use one C++-specific header file and one C++-specific statement, which makes the code C++. ***But*** you don't use any other C++-specific code, all the rest could be almost plain C. What are you trying to learn, C or C++?

Comment: And either way, not even whatever resource you use to learn "C in C++" does a very good job at teaching you C either. The `std::malloc` function allocates a specific number of *bytes*, not "objects". The size of e.g. `char *` is different from the size of `char`. You are simply not allocating enough memory, and go out of bounds of the memory you have allocated. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why is `ascii` an array of `char` rather than `bool`?

Comment: There are also a lot of other problems, and questionable code. Take for example the `ascii` array, what is it really supposed to represent? Because right now all it contains are a "boolean" equivalence, where only the `','` and `' '` characters are "true". And since you use the local encoding of your system, it might not even correspond or be related to anything about ASCII at all.

Comment: I just use cpp.sh this site to compile my c code, now I use https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler <- this site and change headers e.g. stdio.h, stdlib.h but same happening occurred.

Comment: now I'm learning C, so I don't use boolean type sorry for confusing you guys

Comment: C have a `bool` type, it was introduced with the C99 standard over 20 years ago. And if you're learning C, why are you using C++ headers and statements? And in C most (if not all) of your casting isn't needed. You do yourself a disservice to mix languages like that while learning. Get some decent C beginners books and learn C properly.

Comment: Oh and adding to the list of problems, you need to think about the order in which you check for string terminator. Your `strlen` function can count the null-terminator which isn't supposed to be included in the string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a ghastly number of years since I've done C code, but from what I recall, this line:

```
char **ans = (char **)malloc(wc);
```

will only give you one byte for each word in the string, when you actually need a pointer's length.  I believe what you actually want there is:

```
char **ans = (char **)calloc(wc, sizeof(char*));
```

Also, why are you bothering learning C??  Even if you ignore the object-oriented features of it, C++ is a much "Better C" (that's one of it's design goals), and give you things like `bool`.

Comment: do you know ecole 42? this curriculum teaching about C language, so I started learning C 1month ago, and so until now I didn't know C has a bool 

Comment: `bool` was added to C in its C99 standard (23 years ago). (10+ years after it was in the C++89 standard).  but the number of C programmer who learned it post-C99 is tiny compared to the number who learned the earlier C90 standard, it gets forgotten.